# upload multiple files from a form react js throgh axios

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to do multiple file upload i am only able to do one file now how can i upload 3 files from differt input fileds

```
import React from "react";
import axios, { post } from "axios";
;
import moment from "moment";
import "./calendar.css";

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  
    this.state = {
    
    
     
      image_file: null,
      image_preview: "",
      file: null,
    };
    this.onsubmbit = this.onsubmbit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
   
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      allValues: { ...this.state.allValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
    });
  };

  onChange(e) {
   
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);


    let image_as_files = e.target.files[0];

    this.setState({
     
      image_file: image_as_files,
    });

  }
  

  onsubmbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.image_file !== null) {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("scanReport", this.state.image_file);
    

      axios
        .post(
          "url/",
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
              "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(`Success` + res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };


 
 

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      
          <form onSubmit={this.onsubmbit}>
            <div className="module-wrap" style={styles.module}>
             
                <h4>Upload Scan Report</h4>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="file"
                  name="ScanReport"
                  // accept="application/pdf"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.allValues.ScanReport}
                />
                <h4>Upload Blood Report</h4>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="BloodReport"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.allValues.BloodReport}
                />
                <h4>Upload Antenatal Charts</h4>
                <input
                  type="file"
                  name="AntenatalCharts"
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.allValues.AntenatalCharts}
                />
                <h4>Enter Today BP</h4>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="bp"
                  onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  value={this.state.allValues.bp}
                />
                <h4>Enter Todays Weight</h4>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="Weight"
                  onChange={this.changeHandler}
                  value={this.state.allValues.Weight}
                />
              </div>

              <br />

              <div>
                <button type="submit" style={styles.sbtn}>
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
      
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

i am trying to do multiple file upload i am only able to do one file now how can i upload 3 files from differt input fileds
i am trying to do multiple file upload i am only able to do one file now how can i upload 3 files from differt input fileds

Comment: Does the server only support "multipart/form-data" content type ? If it supports a JSON body you could send the base64 encoded files as an array in the JSON body.

Comment: i dont want  base64   `let image_as_files = e.target.files[0]; `  using this i am able to set only the first file how to get the 2nd and thid file and appand that form data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you already have it working for the one file (ScanReport), thus all you need to do is update your `onChange` method to be aware of the input `name` attribute to support multiple file inputs. And then update your class state accordingly.

Thus your state should look something like this:

```js
this.state = {
  allValues: {
    AppointmentDate: "",
    Date: "",
    ScanDate: "",
    question: "",
    ScanReport: "",
    BloodReport: "",
    AntenatalCharts: "",
    Weight: "",
  },
  files: {
    ScanReport: null, // <- these keys should match the 'name' of the inputs
    BloodReport: null,
    AntenatalCharts: null
  },
  image_preview: "",
  file: null,
}
```

Then update your `onChange` to use the name attribute to set it accordingly:

```js
onChange(e) {
  let files = this.state.files
  files[e.target.name] = e.target.files[0]

  this.setState({  
    files: files
  });
}
```

And then finally when you construct the FormData you can add each individual file with the required field name in the form data:

```js
let formData = new FormData();

// EDIT: added logic to handle null files
if (this.state.files.ScanReport != null) {
  formData.append("scanReport", this.state.files.ScanReport);
}
if (this.state.files.BloodReport != null) {
  formData.append("bloodReport", this.state.files.BloodReport);
}
if (this.state.files.AntenatalCharts != null) {
  formData.append("antenatalCharts", this.state.files.AntenatalCharts);
}

...
```

Comment: thnku for the response but now when i try to upload 1 file at a time i get error

Comment: Welcome to the world of software :) You would have to incorporate error handling for when files aren't picked.  I'll update my answer, but this technically isn't part of the same question anymore though so if you find any more hiccups consider creating a new question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If this solves your initial question of uploading multiple files please remember to mark an accepted answer to this question. It helps keep Stackoverflow neat and tidy :)